# How to prevent infinite retries - Apache Shiro RESTful service

Tags: rest, security, tomcat, shiro

**Goal**
I am setting up a RESTful webservice, using RESTEasy framework. For security I use Apache Shiro. I want my api to stop accepting requests or timing out persons that login too much.

**Problem**
Whenever I go some URL with my browser (chrome), I can try to login infinitely many times. Seems a really bad idea to allow this. As a measure, I have made sure to remember the nr of login attempts, for which users cannot login after 3 times. However, with a brute force attack, you could still block all users from loging in. I want a more general solution.

**Shiro.ini**

```
[main]
# We store users and passwords inside the realm.
myRealm = com.myproject.shiro.DatabaseRealm
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

[urls]
/api/version = anon
/api/** = authcBasic
```

**DatabaseRealm**

```
public class DatabaseRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principalCollection) {
        // No clue what to do with this functin. I only use authentication and not authorization, so probably just nothing.
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Check if the user inputted is valid. The user can login if holds:
     * 1. Password is correct. (if not, nrOfLogonAttempts++)
     * 2. LogonUser.nrOfLogonAttemps is less than 3
     * 3. LogonUser.dateEndValid is null or >= today.
     * @param authenticationToken Token with basic information.
     * @return SimpleAuthenticationInfo
     * @throws AuthenticationException Whenever the user cannot login.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken)
            throws UnknownAccountException, IncorrectCredentialsException, LockedAccountException, ExpiredCredentialsException {
        // Connect with the database.
        DbContext context = null;
        try {
            context = DbContextUtil.getContextFromTomcat();
            // Lookup user in the database.
            LogonUserMyDao logonUserMyDao = new LogonUserMyDao(context);
            LogonuserPojo logonuserPojo = logonUserMyDao.fetchOneByUsername(((UsernamePasswordToken) authenticationToken).getUsername());
            if (logonuserPojo == null) {
                throw new UnknownAccountException("Could not find user.");
            }

            // Check password
            String plainTextPassword = new String(((UsernamePasswordToken) authenticationToken).getPassword());
            if (!BCryptUtil.checkPassword(plainTextPassword, logonuserPojo.getPassword())) {
                // We will note this event.
                logonuserPojo.setNroflogonattempts(logonuserPojo.getNroflogonattempts() + 1);
                logonUserMyDao.update(logonuserPojo);
                context.commit();
                throw new IncorrectCredentialsException("Incorrect password.");
            }

            // Check nrOfLogonAttempts
            if (logonuserPojo.getNroflogonattempts() >= 2) {
                throw new LockedAccountException("Cannot login anymore.");
            }

            // Check date
            if (logonuserPojo.getDateendvalid() != null && DateTimeUtil.isBeforeToday(logonuserPojo.getDateendvalid())) {
                throw new ExpiredCredentialsException("Account is expired.");
            }

            // User is valid, so return some info.
            return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(logonuserPojo.getUsername(), plainTextPassword, getClass().getName());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            MyLogger.logError("Could not connect to user database.", e);
            throw new AuthenticationException("Could not connect to databse.");
        } finally {
            if (context != null) {
                try {
                    context.getConnection().close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    MyLogger.logError("Could not close connection", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for more general DDOS protection? There are a few options out there depending on where your app is running (for example AWS Shield).

You could also prevent connections from reaching your db with something like this: https://github.com/iTransformers/ddos-servlet-filter (but, that that would still require handling the request in your application)

On the Shiro side of things, counting your attempts is NOT a bad idea, but you need to watch out for the user management side of things (How does a user get unlocked, support request? Wait 30 minutes?)  Instead of recording failures, you may just want to record/audit all attempts (excluding the actual password of course). With either option a call to support or an `n` minute window, this may help provide some context to support or an easy query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I really liked your last paragraph with suggestions. It gives me food for thought. I am not looking for a general DDOS protection, but really a security protection.